# What happens with values when WeakMap itself is GC-ed in v8

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8

WeakMaps are useful when the life of the key is shorter than the life of the Map itself. However, I could imagine the situation when the life of the map and the life of the key are completely independent (i.e. WeakMap itself could be garbage collected before one of its keys was):

```
var wm = new WeakMap();
var obj = {};
wm.set(obj, someHeavyData); 
wm = null; // obj is still alive.
```

In the example above `obj` is still alive. However, we could not reach `someHeavyData` anymore since the original WeakMap is garbage collected. Thus, `someHeavyData` should be garbage collected too. Nevertheless, I suspect that it won't be GC-ed and will produce a memory leak, since (as I understand) WeakMaps in v8 are implemented somehow (roughly) like:

```
class WeakMap {

    constructor() { 
       this.symbol = Symbol(); 
    }

    get(key) { 
       return key[this.symbol]; 
    }

    set(key, value) { 
       key[this.symbol] = value; 
       return this;
    } 
}
```

that means that if any data was once stored under the key in some weak map, it will be stored into the key as a strong reference (that's why the key should be an object in WeakMaps) and will not be garbage collected until the key itself is garbage collected.

Can anybody tell me that I'm wrong, and it WILL be garbage collected?

One can tell me to choose Map over the WeakMap when I know in advance that the map will be garbage collected before its keys. Unfortunately, there are plenty of legitimate situations when it is not known in advance. For example, two-dimensional WeakMap:

```
class WeakMap2D {

   constructor () {
      this.wm1 = new WeakMap();
   }

   get(key1, key2) {
      var vm2 = this.vm1.get(key1);
      return vm2 && vm2.get(key2);
   }

   set(key1, key2, value) {
      var vm2 = this.vm1.get(key1);
      if (!vm2) {
         vm2 = new WeakMap();
         this.vm1.set(key1, vm2);
      }
      vm2.set(key2, value);
      return this;
   }

}
```

Using this class we can write:

```
var secrets = new WeakMap2D();
var alice = {}, bob = {};
secrets.set(alice, bob, HugeSecretData);
alice = null;
```

Here by the intention, we want that HugeSecretData should be GC-ed as soon as either `bob` or `alice` is GC-ed. And it looks like that it will be GC-ed only when the second key (namely `bob`) is garbage collected.

Once more: anybody, please tell me that I'm wrong, and explain how and when this data will be garbage collected.

Comment: I believe this will not be v8 specific?

Comment: @thefourtheye, of course! However, I believe that it _could be_ implementation specific. And it would be great to obtain the answer for all engines. My first interest is the answer for v8. Then for others.

Comment: As far as I know, the key isn't modified by the weakmap. So you're sample of code is kind of wrong. It could be mapped into an other object. Where the link between the key and the value is within the `WeakMap` only, so when `WeakMap` is garbage collected, even if there is still references on the key, the value will get GCed if there is no more reference to it. And in any case, there is no real way to know when something will get GCed, what's important is that there are no references to it.

Comment: The question is why do you care in which order something will get GCed?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, of course, key is not _observably_ modified by the WeakMap.set. But this doesn't mean that it is not modified internally. Your comment could be an answer to my question if you could point to the v8 source code, where it is obvious that  the "link between the key and the value is within the WeakMap only and the key is not modified". I'll try to find it myself, and together we could find it faster.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix - I don't care in wich order something will get GCed, I care the conditions when something will be available for GC. I'm trying to avoid memory leaks. For example, if the key is really holding the strong reference to the value (in some invisible slot), then the value will never get GCed while there are references to the key. If the key is something that lives forever, then this behavior will produce a memory leak and exhaust all the memory when used repeatedly.

Comment: Btw, this is a very succinct way to describe the concept: "WeakMaps are useful when the life of the key is shorter than the life of the Map itself".

Comment: I am not sure what implementation does V8 use, but some JS engines were at least considering the use of "inverted weak map implementation", which modify the keys internally (the values are internally stored in the key). See https://esdiscuss.org/topic/removal-of-weakmap-weakset-clear and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101817.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should answer your question:

```
var obj = {}
var weakmap = null;

while(true) {
  weakmap = new WeakMap()
  weakmap.set(obj, new Uint32Array(2048))
}
```

As you can see, obj is never freed but `weakmap` is changed for a new `weakmap` then the old should get freed. If I run this in `NodeJS`, it will free memory and this infinite loop doesn't end up taking all memory. That said, the `WeakMap` is working as expected and there is no memory leak. Your assumption that the `key` keep a reference to the `value` is wrong because in that case, the `WeakMap` wouldn't be a real `WeakMap`.

It would take a few seconds to fill your memory with `Uint32Array(2048)`.